# "Dispose is cancel" sementic on C# Tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, idisposable

I wanted to have a `Task` implementation that whenever it is get disposed, the task associated is canceled. So I have the following naive implementation in mind

```
public class AutoCancelTask : Task, IDisposable
{
    public static AutoCancelTask Create(Action<CancellationToken> a)
    {
        return new AutoCancelTask(a, new CancellationTokenSource());
    }

    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    internal AutoCancelTask(Action<CancellationToken> a, CancellationTokenSource cts)
        :base((() => a(cts.Token)))
    { this.cts = cts; }

    void IDisposable.Dispose(){
        cts.Cancel();
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

To simplify I only consider the simplest `Task` constructor. Adding other constructors would not be hard anyway.

My concern is how the IDisposable interface is being implemented. Since Task also implements IDisposable, would the above code cause any problems in certain scenarios? More importantly, would the above code do the right thing?

Comment: Good question. What you're doing feels like a hacky abuse of the fact that `Task` is not sealed. While I cannot tell you what the exact implications of what you're doing would be if you dispose of tasks when you shouldn't, as per PFX blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx) you should not generally dispose of tasks anyway, so you can *theoretically* hijack the `Dispose(bool)` method by overriding it with your cancellation logic while leaving out the `base.Dispose` call.

Comment: Also, if that's your goal, overriding `Dispose(bool)` is the right way to go, *not* introducing an explicit `IDisposable.Dispose` implementation - as that will only be called in a small subset of scenarios that I can think of.

Comment: Well, it looks like this question is actually belong to "codereview" stack exchange though :)

Comment: Finally, I feel obligated to point out that this is an extremely basic use of `CancellationTokenSource` and what you're doing isn't really worth the risk, but as a theoretical exercise it's really fun.

Comment: I know how `CancellationTokenSource` being used. For ease of use though, the `using` grammar sugar is applicable to `AutoCancelTask`, and this is the purpose of this.

Comment: Also, the fact is none of the `Dispose` methods in `Task` is overridable. This is why my only option is to use explicit interface implementation

Comment: In the latest .NET source (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,29d432e77814898d) `Dispose(bool)` is virtual. Not sure about previous versions.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But intellisense didn't know it.

Comment: If the `using` pattern is what you're after, the most sensible approach is to create an `IDisposable` wrapper around `CancellationTokenSource` - so that you can use its `Token` as you normally would, and auto-cancel on `wrapper.Dispose`. You'll get a lot more reuse out of such a component as then it's only responsible for cancellation and doesn't force particular `Task` semantics (so you get better separation of concerns AND reduced risk of breaking changes).